# Is there a Korean version of Google Ngrams?

Tags: resources

https://books.google.com/ngrams allows you to look at the frequency of usage of a term over time, or compare multiple terms.

Is there any similar thing for Korean words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into [꼬꼬마 세종말뭉치](http://kkma.snu.ac.kr/search), or [국립국어원 말뭉치검색](https://ithub.korean.go.kr/user/corpus/corpusSearchManager.do). If you're interested in etymology, look into [국립국어원 국어 어휘 역사](http://korean.go.kr/front/wordLocal/wordHistoryList.do?mn_id=116).

I don't think there exists any service which shows you the frequency over time, though. It's also harder and more expensive to apply to the Korean language, where there are numerous particles and verb endings which obscure words' original forms. Also almost every word looked different before the major reforms of the 20th century.

Google Ngrams is a side-project of Google Books that took many years, digitizing every book page by page, by OCR and by hand(using Captchas). I don't think that would work for Korean. There just aren't enough time, money, technology, interest, and resources.